# Webpack: configure path mapping

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-config

This is probably a trivial problem, but I am new to webpack. I have a project where the include paths seem to be messed up. The project structure looks like this (simplified):

```
app/
├─ webpack.config.js
├─ dist/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main.js
│  ├─ modules/
│  │  ├─ button/
│  │  │  ├─ button.js
│  │  ├─ link/
│  │  │  ├─ link.js
      ... many more
```

Note that each module has its own subfolder. The `main.js` looks like this:

```js
import './modules/button';
import './modules/link';
...
```

Modules can import other modules:

```js
// app/src/modules/button/button.js
import { mediaLink } from '../link';
```

I have a basic `webpack.config.js` set up that looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
};
```

For some reason, all imports don't consider the module's subfolders.
When i run `webpack`, I get a lot of `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ...` errors. The error output looks like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './modules/button' in '/path/to/project/app/src'
 @ ./src/main.js 8:0-27
```

Can I configure webpack to use some kind of mapping when it imports a module?

Comment: `main.js` doesn't need to import anything just for the sake of importing them..

Comment: @AKX: I did so, let me edit the question

Comment: Okay, can you show some of the real errors, please?

Comment: @AKX: I added actual error output to the question

Answer (score 1):

If the tree is

```
├─ src/
│  ├─ main.js
│  ├─ modules/
│  │  ├─ button/
│  │  │  ├─ button.js
```

then `src/main.js` will need to

```
import './modules/button/button';
```

or, if `button.js` [was named `index.js` (`resolve.mainFiles`)](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfiles),

```
import './modules/button';
```

would work.

Yes, you *can* set up aliases/mappings, but that's probably not worth it (especially when you consider your IDE/editor/... would also need to know about the mappings).

Just try renaming those `button/button.js`es and `link/link.js`es to `button/index.js`, `link/index.js` etc. first.

Comment: Renaming the module files to `index.js` did work. Do you have any idea why the project looks like this? Could the creator have used another module bundler where paths have to look like that?

Comment: Yeah, that's always possible.